# Can't kill Go Server

Tags: go

I tried to search for solution for this problem for hours but couldn't find it.

Problem: After I start a golang server by typing "go run server.go" then after Im done with it  I press Ctrl + C but the server is still up (I can still connect to server through reactjs frontend). Whats going on?

I even tried to kill terminal from VSCode but still it work as desired.

How to manually kill this server from terminal?

Mac OS Catalina

Comment: What OS? And what does `netstat` show for the port you're serving on?

Comment: It is Mac OS Catalina. I had to restart my mbp at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your OS.  If you're running Windows, you can go into the windows process manager and find the process that's running your server.go and kill it manually.

If you're on MacOS or Linux, you should be able to handle this with a terminal:

1. Open another terminal and execute `ps aux | grep server.go`
2. Find the associated process ID (pid) with your server.go process (it should be the number listed second in the response from step 1)
3. Run a `kill -9 PID` where PID is the process ID you found in step 2.

Comment: yes and when you have a unique identifer of that running process you can zap it with a `killall xxxxxx` as in `killall server.go`